# read data in database to checkboxlist, how can i read it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I read the data in the database so when it reads. it will check the specific data?

Here is my full code:

```
string query = "SELECT TypeName from TypeTransaction WHERE UANumber = '" + id + "'";

        connUser.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(sdr.Read())
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = sdr.GetString(0);
            lbTypes.Items.Add(item);
        }
        List<string> iteme = new List<string>();
        for(int j = 0; j < lbTypes.Items.Count; j++)
        { 
            for(int i = 0;i < chkTypes.Items.Count;i++)
            {
                if(lbTypes.Items[j].Text == chkTypes.Items[i].Text)
                {
                    chkTypes.Items[i].Selected = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    chkTypes.Items[i].Selected = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

my listbox has a value of `GDS and Email` in a seperate line, but when i run it, the `Email` Checkbox is the one only selected. it should be both `Email` and `GDS` that is selected in the checkboxlist.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on below url which helps you
[http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-CheckBoxList-from-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-CheckBoxList-from-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx)